# What is the most accurate errno val to use for fgets failures?

Tags: c, fgets, errno

Say I successfully open a file for reading using fopen, but fgets fails. I want my function to set errno appropriately.

There are many errno vals associated with file operations, but none seem explicit to "something happened while reading this.". fgets also does not set errno.

What is the closest errno value to use for failures reading from an already open file?

Comment: Why is `fgets()` failing?

Comment: The normal reason for `fgets()` to fail is because you're at EOF. That's not really an error, there's no reason to set `errno`.

Comment: @Barmar fgets isn't failing, but its documentation says it can. Every other path of execution in my program communicates using errno, so I want to be as close as possible here for future potential failures.

Comment: `EIO = Input/Output Error`

Comment: If fgets fails, it will have set errno itself to indicate the reason. No need for you to do so.

Comment: @R.. fgets' man page does not say anything about errno in event of failures.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool: Then that's a deficiency in the man page. The specification is that it can fail for any of the reasons `fgetc` does: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html

Comment: @R.. You should be the answer guy

Comment: OK, done.......

Comment: The C standard doesn't say that any input function sets `errno` (other than `EILSEQ` for an encoding error). Secondary standards like POSIX might impose more requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the C standard itself rarely mandates `errno` be set, assuming you're on a POSIX or POSIX-like system, `fgets` will already be setting `errno` to an appropriate value for you. See the specification for `fgets`:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html

which specifies that it can fail for any of the reasons defined for `fgetc`:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html

The reason it's done that way is that both C and POSIX specify all the compound stdio functions in terms of repeated calls to `fgetc` or `fputc`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EIO` if your implementation defines it. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) defines `EIO` as "Input/output error".